# Regular expression to capture between two words

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following patterns within string

```
[[at the Location ]]
[[Location at]]
[[Location]]
```

I want to replace `[[at the Location ]]` to be from example at home I tried

```
var result = Regex.Match(equivalentSentense, @"\[[(.*?)\ ]]");
```

but this will return the first pattern any idea how to replace word location only and remove `]]` or `[[`.

Comment: can you provide a sample data and your expected output?

Comment: I wonder how [`@"\[[(.*?)\ ]]"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5b(.*%3f)+%5d%5d&i=%5b%5bat+the+Location+%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5bLocation+at%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5bLocation%5d%5d) could return you anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
 {
    public static void Main()
    {
        var equivalentSentence = "[[at the Location ]] [[Location at]] [[Location]]";       

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[\[(?<location>(.*?)) \]\]");

        Match match = regex.Match(equivalentSentence);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            var location = match.Groups["location"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(location);
        }
    }
}
```